# Taking a vector derivative of a vector component

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, chain-rule

I'm trying to understand a result I saw in my Chaos Theory course.

I have a vector $\vec{A}$ and I'm focusing on its $x$ component:

$$A_x = xp^2-p_x(\vec{r} . \vec{p}) - \frac{kmx}{r}$$

It is given that: $\vec{r} = r \hat{r}$.

I don't understand how the following derivative is defined:

$$\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial \vec{r}} = \hat{x}p^2-p_x\vec{p}-\frac{km}{r}\hat{x} + \frac{kmx}{r^3}\vec{r}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably a combination of three partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial r_x}$, $\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial r_y}$, $\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial r_z}$.

Comment: Also, it seems that $x=r_x$